# Add object to NSMutableArray from other class

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I have a view controller class called `PresidentsViewController` that sets up data in a `UITableView`. This data is in the form of `NSMutableArray` called `list`. I have another class, `PresidentAddController`, that is supposed to handle adding an object of type `President` to this list based on user inputted data about a president. However, I can't get the object to add to the list. I have confirmed that the user inputted data for a new president is being collected correctly, so it is adding to the list that's in another class that's causing problems. I believe the correct code to add an object to the list is:

```
[pvc.list addObject:newPresident];
```

However, I don't know how to properly create the reference/instance/? (which is what pvc would be) to PresidentsViewController inside of PresidentAddController so that I can properly add a new president to the list. I am not using Interface Builder for this because it is just a UITableView.

How do I add a president to the list in this situation?

**Edit:** Here is how the array is being initialized:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *list;
```

And here is how PresidentAddController is being set up in PresidentsViewController:

```
PresidentAddController *childController = [[PresidentAddController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
childController.title = @"Add President";
[self.navigationController pushViewController:childController animated:YES];
[childController release];
```

Comment: Can you post your code where you initialize your mutable array and set it s properties?

Comment: I just edited the question to include that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a pointer to `PresidentAddController` this way:

```
// in @interface
PresidentsViewController *listController;

@property (nonatomic, assign) PresidentsViewController *listController;

// in @implementation
@synthesize listController;
```

Then when you instantiate your `PresidentAddController`, set the pointer:

```
PresidentAddController *childController = 
  [[PresidentAddController alloc]
   initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
childController.title = @"Add President";
childController.listController = self;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:childController animated:YES];
[childController release];
```

So then you can go `[listController.list addObject:newPresident];` in `PresidentAddController`.

**EDIT:** `childController.listController = self` calls `[childController setListController:self]`, which in turn reads the `@synthesize`d method in your implementation and sets the pointer `*listController` to point to the current class (if you're writing code in the `PresidentsViewController` class, then `self` is going to be the current instance of `PresidentsViewController`).

The reason why I use `assign` is because if you were to use `retain`, then when you set `listController` to `self` it will actually keep an owning reference to the object. This can cause all sorts of problems if you ever try to deallocate `PresidentsViewController`, because if you have an owning reference in `PresidentAddController` then it will not deallocate until that reference is also released. Using `assign` ensures that if you ever release the `PresidentsViewController` before `PresidentAddController` disappears, it will be properly deallocated. Of course, maybe you want to keep it around in that situation, in which case using `retain` here is also fine.

Comment: Thanks for the response -- see my edits for how PresidentAddController is being initialized. Yes to your first question.

Comment: Updated the answer following your clarifications :)

Comment: This works! Would you mind explaining exactly what `childController.listController = self;` does? That seems to be the line of code I needed. Also, for the @property declaration, was it necessary to make it "assign" because you were going to be setting it to "self"?

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion here would be that you have a property defined as `@property (nonatomic,copy) NSMutableArray *list;`  Are you getting and exception trying to add the object into the array?  If so, it's likely because the copy modifier is returning an immutable copy of the array.  Try to create a method that takes the object and adds it to the list without using `self.list` ... just `[list addObject]` and if that works then this is your problem.

Comment: No, I'm not getting an exception. I believe it's a problem with accessing the class PresidentsViewController in the first place, but I'm not sure. What would be the correct way of setting up the reference/instance without having to alloc/init PresidentsViewController again because that does not work?